# Electromagnet Circuit

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, electromagnetism

I'm working on a small project to power a magnetic lock that deactivates when a series of switches are turned on. I've re-designed my circuit based on help from another post, but isn't supplying the correct voltage to the magnet. Any ideas?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHr9pw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Here's an updated circuit that takes into account the recommended changes

Comment: What is "the correct voltage" and what do you actually measure? What is the intended purpose of R2 & R3? (please don't say that they're a voltage divider used to power the logic gate ...)

Comment: MC14002 appears to be a NOR gate rather than a NOT gate, so there is an error in the schematic.

Comment: Even if the logic is a NOT gate,  the input to NOT gate is floating when switches are open.  Not a good idea

Comment: @ Marla You are correct in that the MC14002 is a NOR Gate, I simply labeled it as a NOT because that's the purpose its serving. Regarding the floating - should the input have a pull down resistor to prevent that? I only just learned about the dangers of floating.

Comment: @brhans the magnet operates at 12v, 150mA. What I measured was a drop of ~1.3v across the magnet. The voltage divider is there to power the logic gate, so if that's gonna cause issues in the circuit I'd love to know a better way.

Comment: Inputs should always have a defined logic state. A pull down resistor should be used, yes.  With 4000 series logic, you could use a high value resistor such as 470K to reduce power consumption.

Comment: 4000-series CMOS logic will happily run from 12V - get rid of that voltage divider (and remember in future that a voltage divider is never, ever, ever, ever a power supply. ever.). Put a pull-down on the logic input (pretty much whatever resistor you have in the 1k-1M range should work fine with a CMOS gate).

Comment: I put it there as the threshold voltage on the transistor was listed as 2-4v. My understanding was that I want a voltage of 2-4v to be output from the logic gate so as not to fry the transistor. Does that make sense or am I still missing something?

Comment: The FET's gate threshold voltage is the voltage at which it will just barely begin to 'turn on'. If you want it to be a good switch you'll need to give it substantially more than that. Just be sure you stay below the maximum gate voltage to avoid killing it. If you did need a voltage divider to limit the gate voltage, the place to put it would be between the logic gate output & the FET.

Comment: The international language of EE people is the circuit diagram. On this basis yours needs to be accurate and not sloppy else crap in = crap out.

Comment: @Andyaka - Noted. I'll post a better one with the suggested improvements.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the schematic

Answer (score 3):

Why not just switch the mosfet directly? Its not as if you are using the logic gate to perform any logical combination.

[image]

Comment: This totally works as well - the only reason I'm using the gate is that I already have a bunch of SPST switches lying around that I wanted to use.

Comment: @TheEngineEar Not a problem. Just fit some of the SPST switches upside down (or at different angles) so that they don't all switch ON in the same physical direction. Your combination could then be DOWN UP UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT etc. (whatever you choose it to be).

Comment: @JlmDearden - my plan exactly!